# Where do I find freshly installed apps on windows 2012 server (and windows 8)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-8.1

After installing an application (like SQL server management studio) Where can I find it's link to run it ?!!!

(I know I can try to find it using Search, and then if I remember the right name - pin it to the metro board) -  but if I don't do all of this, or if I don't remember the app's name - how do I find what to run after installing a program on windows 8.1 / Server 2012 ? 
I must miss something b/c it can't be the official way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the metro start page, left under the icons there is a down arrow button. CLick it - it goes to the "all installed apps" repository. This will have a group for SQL Server (because sql server creates a folder).

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's another way, although this list contains far too much icons, it's a new server with only sql installed. on my laptop if I do this, I get about 250 icons. is there any smart way to put them in "folders" like the old start->programs menu ?

Comment: You can create groups and pull those you need to the front. Normally remember hte name and just start typing, it filters. "sql" is a good filter.

Comment: @Dani if you can't remember the name for search, and you can't find it in an alphabetical list sorted by product, I don't think any organizational system could really help you there. Even the legacy start menu was organized by application... If you know the application name, launching it is the exact same workflow as Windows 7 - hit the Windows key, type the app name, hit enter.

Comment: thanks, I will try the group solution, untill today I used fences to solve it, after looking for the files myself....

Comment: @MDMarra - having more than 80 apps installed on my machine, I used to sort them in a tree, and find them easily, can't do it on a flat UI, I will try the groups suggested here. it might help.

Comment: There are also 3rd party apps like: http://retroui.com/retrouiserver.asp if you really want to go back to the old GUI style.

Comment: You can also do as TomTom mentions and then by "Apps" change it from `by name` to `by date installed`.  This helps especially after a new install to see what got added without knowing the exact title the app menu gave it.

Comment: Very good tip - one I did not know. Yes, normally that is idiotic (who remembers when he installed something after some time) but for totally NEW installs that will put all new items on one end, and this is a VERY VERY VERY good tip ;) Have to remember that ;)

Comment: The problem is that this list is over populated.